# PJSIP Not Responding with Authentication to a 401

Tags: ios, asterisk, pjsip

I'm trying to get PJSIP working in my iOS project to connect to my Asterisk server. I did a packet capture with wireshark and for some reason PJSIP isn't responding to the 401 challenge like it should.

What's more odd, is that one a rare occasion, it does work. Like there is some sort of race condition going on but that would all exist within PJSIP itself. Because all I call is...

```
pjsua_acc_add(&accountConfig, PJ_TRUE, &accID);
```

and then the PJSIP libraries do their thing.

Here's a snippet of the packet capture.. 10.200.0.72 is my Asterisk server. 10.200.154.118 is my test iOS device.

```
REGISTER sip:10.200.0.72 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.200.154.118:5080;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjLjNBXVcaqqPqYVtTR2GDEQJhhGYG7Fo3
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:110@10.200.0.72>;tag=JgDAcidZf0Ew-Jqgei0Am3Znyl2SEFg.
To: <sip:110@10.200.0.72>
Call-ID: hTMu0Vi.Kte6PntnMJdxQmeBWtKdXZd0
CSeq: 59555 REGISTER
Contact: <sip:110@10.200.154.118:5080;ob>
Expires: 300
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Content-Length:  0

REGISTER sip:10.200.0.72 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.200.154.118:5080;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjLjNBXVcaqqPqYVtTR2GDEQJhhGYG7Fo3
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:110@10.200.0.72>;tag=JgDAcidZf0Ew-Jqgei0Am3Znyl2SEFg.
To: <sip:110@10.200.0.72>
Call-ID: hTMu0Vi.Kte6PntnMJdxQmeBWtKdXZd0
CSeq: 59555 REGISTER
Contact: <sip:110@10.200.154.118:5080;ob>
Expires: 300
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Content-Length:  0

SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.200.154.118:5080;rport=5080;received=10.200.154.118;branch=z9hG4bKPjLjNBXVcaqqPqYVtTR2GDEQJhhGYG7Fo3
Call-ID: hTMu0Vi.Kte6PntnMJdxQmeBWtKdXZd0
From: <sip:110@10.200.0.72>;tag=JgDAcidZf0Ew-Jqgei0Am3Znyl2SEFg.
To: <sip:110@10.200.0.72>;tag=z9hG4bKPjLjNBXVcaqqPqYVtTR2GDEQJhhGYG7Fo3
CSeq: 59555 REGISTER
WWW-Authenticate: Digest  realm="asterisk",nonce="1485330086/50f04167f65383db99f5c0cf17651984",opaque="73b3a6a8599485f8",algorithm=md5,qop="auth"
Server: FPBX-13.0.190.11(13.12.1)
Content-Length:  0

SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.200.154.118:5080;rport=5080;received=10.200.154.118;branch=z9hG4bKPjLjNBXVcaqqPqYVtTR2GDEQJhhGYG7Fo3
Call-ID: hTMu0Vi.Kte6PntnMJdxQmeBWtKdXZd0
From: <sip:110@10.200.0.72>;tag=JgDAcidZf0Ew-Jqgei0Am3Znyl2SEFg.
To: <sip:110@10.200.0.72>;tag=z9hG4bKPjLjNBXVcaqqPqYVtTR2GDEQJhhGYG7Fo3
CSeq: 59555 REGISTER
WWW-Authenticate: Digest  realm="asterisk",nonce="1485330086/50f04167f65383db99f5c0cf17651984",opaque="73b3a6a8599485f8",algorithm=md5,qop="auth"
Server: FPBX-13.0.190.11(13.12.1)
Content-Length:  0
```

Here's my OBJ-C Code for getting this going...

```
- (void) startAndRegisterOnServer:(NSString *)sipDomain withUserName:(NSString *)sipUser andPassword:(NSString *)password success:(void (^)(void))success failure:(void (^)(int errorCode, NSString *errorMessage))failure
{
    pj_status_t status;

    status = pjsua_create();

    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
    {
        failure (status, @"Error in pjsua_create");

        return;
    }

    // Setup Config and Initialize

    pjsua_config config;
    pjsua_config_default (&config);

    config.cb.on_incoming_call = &on_incoming_call;
    config.cb.on_call_media_state = &on_call_media_state;
    config.cb.on_call_state = &on_call_state;
    config.cb.on_reg_state2 = &on_reg_state2;

    pjsua_logging_config logConfig;
    pjsua_logging_config_default(&logConfig);
    logConfig.console_level = 5;

    status = pjsua_init(&config, &logConfig, NULL);

    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
    {
        failure (status, @"Error in pjsua_init");

        return;
    }

    // Add UDP transport

    pjsua_transport_config udpTransportConfig;
    pjsua_transport_config_default(&udpTransportConfig);
    udpTransportConfig.port = 5080;

    status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, &udpTransportConfig, NULL);

    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
    {
        failure (status, @"Error adding UDP transport");

        return;
    }

    // Add TCP transport.

    pjsua_transport_config tcpTransportConfig;
    pjsua_transport_config_default(&tcpTransportConfig);
    tcpTransportConfig.port = 5080;

    status = pjsua_transport_create(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TCP, &tcpTransportConfig, NULL);

    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
    {
        failure (status, @"Error adding TCP transport");

        return;
    }

    // Startup PJSUA

    status = pjsua_start();

    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
    {
        failure (status, @"Error starting PJSUA");

        return;
    }

    // Register with SIP Server

    pjsua_acc_config accountConfig;
    pjsua_acc_config_default(&accountConfig);

    // Account ID

    char sipAccount [MAX_SIP_ACCOUNT_LENGTH];
    sprintf (sipAccount, "sip:%s@%s", [sipUser UTF8String], [sipDomain UTF8String]);
    accountConfig.id = pj_str(sipAccount);

    // Register URI

    char regUri[MAX_SIP_REGISTER_URI_LENGTH];
    sprintf(regUri, "sip:%s", [sipDomain UTF8String]);
    accountConfig.reg_uri = pj_str(regUri);

    // Set the credentials in accountConfig

    accountConfig.cred_count = 1;
    accountConfig.cred_info[0].scheme = pj_str("digest");
    accountConfig.cred_info[0].realm = pj_str("asterisk");
    accountConfig.cred_info[0].username = pj_str((char *)[sipUser UTF8String]);
    accountConfig.cred_info[0].data_type = PJSIP_CRED_DATA_PLAIN_PASSWD;
    accountConfig.cred_info[0].data = pj_str((char *)[password UTF8String]);

    pjsua_acc_id accID;

    status = pjsua_acc_add(&accountConfig, PJ_TRUE, &accID);

    [PJSIPInterfaceManager sharedInstance].accountID = accID;

    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
    {
        failure (status, @"Error registering account with server");

        return;
    }

    success();
}
```

Any thoughts? Again on a rare occasion I can get it to work but it's like 1 in 50 times.

---

### ** UPDATE **

---

So after a lot of troubleshooting. I believe this may be NAT related. I have two servers. One is internal to my network which is what this example is based on (10.200.0.72) and an external server. However I am having the issue on both servers. So what follows is the testing I did over night using my external Asterisk server. I left my iOS client running over night continuing to fail to REGISTER. It is set to the default 5 minute retry. It was if it was just resending the same packet all the time as the CSeq was not incrementing. Then in the middle of the night the client finally connected.

In the logs I noticed this...

```
04:19:22.706    pjsua_acc.c  ...SIP registration failed, status=408 (Request Timeout)
04:24:20.767    pjsua_acc.c  ....IP address change detected for account 0 (10.200.154.118:5080 --> [MY EXTERNAL IP]:31943). Updating registration (using method 4)
04:24:20.810    pjsua_acc.c  ....sip:100@[EXTERNAL ASTERISK IP]: registration success, status=200 (OK), will re-register in 300 seconds
```

Please note I redacted the IP of my external Asterisk server and my public IP.

You'll see on the second line that the PJSIP client noticed that my IP changed. It didn't actually, the device kept the 10.200.154.118. But for some reason it suddenly started sending my public IP for my router in the VIA line of the packet. Then you can see in the next line it successfully registers.

Here's the VIA lines from the packet capture...

From:

```
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.200.154.118:5080;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjegwWD-UEDhH3c5cShdumEEbKvfmK45Zl
```

To:

```
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP [MY EXTERNAL IP]:31943;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjxcKgVfSngqxxTy7MnGhZU5Y3RrjpczNr
```

Also the CSeq number also finally incremented and that Authorization header was sent.

Then about 3 hours and 20 minutes later it went back into the failed state again. Yet it was still using my external IP (it hadn't reverted back to it's 10 address.) This is after a flurry of OPTIONS messages being sent by the server. About 20 in a row where the client didn't respond...

```
OPTIONS sip:100@[MY EXTERNAL IP]:31943;ob SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP [EXTERNAL ASTERISK IP]:5060;branch=z9hG4bK6128eaf9;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "Unknown" <sip:Unknown@[EXTERNAL ASTERISK IP]>;tag=as165c224d
To: <sip:100@[MY EXTERNAL IP]:31943;ob>
Contact: <sip:Unknown@[EXTERNAL ASTERISK IP]:5060>
Call-ID: 341a15d536c3a3b45a73567056e34b6b@[EXTERNAL ASTERISK IP]:5060
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
User-Agent: Mozilla
Date: Fri, 27 Jan 2017 14:45:48 GMT
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Length: 0
```

I honestly don't know what this OPTION message is all about. But after about 20 of them in a row the subsequent REGISTER failed and continues to do so.

**I also just noticed something.** The port changes from the static 5080 listening port on the client to a random dynamic port. You'll see this in the two VIA lines. This makes me think that even though I'm seeing the packet in my network it's not getting to the client because it's not listening on that port? Any config I should be setting on the client to fix this?

Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

It's a while ago I worked with PJSIP. I compared your startup code with what I have and here are some differences. Not sure it would help.

At the top I do a:

```
    if (pjsua_acc_get_count() > 0)
    {
        [self unregisterAccount];
    }
```

A bit down:

```
    accountConfig.reg_timeout          = 110;
    accountConfig.ka_interval           = 5;
    accountConfig.allow_contact_rewrite = 0;
```

Finally, here's the `unregisterAccount` method:

```
- (void)unregisterAccount
{    
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        pj_status_t status;
        unsigned    count;

        [self registerThread];

        count = pjsua_acc_get_count();

        if (count > 0)
        {
            pjsua_acc_info* info = calloc(count, sizeof(pjsua_acc_info));

            for (int n = 0; n < count; n++)
            {
                status = pjsua_acc_enum_info(info, &count);

                if (status == PJ_SUCCESS)
                {
                    status = pjsua_acc_del(info[n].id);
                    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Unregister unsuccessful");
                    }
                }
            }

            free(info);
        }

        accountId = -1;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps, but I guess not.  You're not alone, PJSIP and SIP in general is rather tricky to get working in every scenario. Wishing you success!

If nothing helps, I guess PJSIP's forum is still working?

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I gave it a shot. But unfortunately it didn't help. pjsua_acc_get_count() is always 0. I tried it at various spots in my function. Right the very beginning. Right before pjsua_acc_config_default(&accountConfig) and just after that. None worked unfortunately. You are right. It's been a right challenge this one. Been trying to get this to work for 5 days now. Thank you again for trying though to help again.. Much appreciated.

Comment: So the extra options didn't help either (perhaps with different values)?

Comment: Unfortunately they did not. I looked up all the different options that could be set and tried a number of them without any luck. For some reason my PJSIP client won't actually send the authorization header.

Answer (score 1):

So the morale of this story is to make sure your network is up to date. My WIFI setup was of professional grade but it was very out of date. Getting it updated solved all these issues. It wasn't the wired network but specifically the wifi network. Which is why my other devices were working as they were wired.

I finally discovered the issue when I had the notion that this could be the issue and setup an adhoc wifi network on my mac and connected my device to it. Everything started working then. This then led me to the need to update the WIFI AP.

Hopefully my OBJ C code above can help others out as I don't believe I've seen a specific OBJ C example of this setup function. :)